# reformatting a method to fit on one line in IntelliJ IDEA v14?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any keystroke or other way that I can reformat a method to fit on one line?

for instance, this:

```
public double getPi() {
    return 3.14159;
}
```

to this:

```
public double getPi() { return 3.14159; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can collapse that way by pressing the `[-]` on the left column

`CTRL -`